# How to convert the c++ code to Python for automatic image rotation using OpenCV?

Tags: python, image, opencv

I want to do the following:

1. Rotate the `Incoming Image` to align it perfectly with the `Template Image`.
2. Use `cv2.substrate()` to compare the two aligned images & print out the difference.

I already have the Python code to do the image comparison:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

image1 = cv2.imread('letter f5.png') 
image2 = cv2.imread('letter f.png') 

difference = cv2.subtract(image1, image2)

result = np.any(difference) 

if result is True:
    print ("The images are the same")
else:
    cv2.imshow("result.jpg", difference)
    print ("the images are different")
```

The image comparison works well if the two images are aligned. If the `Incoming Image` is off by 90 degree clockwise, the image comparison won't work.

So, how can I rotate this image:

[image: rotated 90 degree clockwise]

To this:

[image: aligned incoming image]

So that I'll be able to compare it with `Template Image`.

I have this c++ code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#define PI 3.14159265

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


void rotate(cv::Mat& src, double angle, cv::Mat& dst)
{
    int len = std::max(src.cols, src.rows);
     cv::Point2f pt(len/2., len/2.);
     cv::Mat r = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(pt, angle, 1.0);

     cv::warpAffine(src, dst, r, cv::Size(len, len));
}



float angleBetween(const Point &v1, const Point &v2)
{
    float len1 = sqrt(v1.x * v1.x + v1.y * v1.y);
    float len2 = sqrt(v2.x * v2.x + v2.y * v2.y);

    float dot = v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;

    float a = dot / (len1 * len2);

    if (a >= 1.0)
        return 0.0;
    else if (a <= -1.0)
        return PI;
    else{
        int degree;
        degree = acos(a)*180/PI;
        return degree;
        };
}



int main()
{

    Mat char1 = imread( "/Users/Rodrane/Documents/XCODE/OpenCV/mkedenemeleri/anarev/rotated.jpg",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

    Mat image = imread("/Users/Rodrane/Documents/XCODE/OpenCV/mkedenemeleri/anarev/gain2000_crop.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );




    if( !char1.data )
    {
        std::cout<< "Error reading object " << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    GaussianBlur( char1, char1, Size(3, 3), 2, 2 );
    GaussianBlur( image, image, Size(3, 3), 2, 2 );
    adaptiveThreshold(char1,char1,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY,9,14);
    adaptiveThreshold(image,image,255,CV_ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C,CV_THRESH_BINARY,9,14);

    //Detect the keypoints using SURF Detector
    int minHessian = 200;

    SurfFeatureDetector detector( minHessian );
    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_object;

    detector.detect( char1, kp_object );

    //Calculate descriptors (feature vectors)
    SurfDescriptorExtractor extractor;
    Mat des_object;

    extractor.compute( char1, kp_object, des_object );

    FlannBasedMatcher matcher;


    namedWindow("Good Matches");

    std::vector<Point2f> obj_corners(4);

    //Get the corners from the object
    obj_corners[0] = cvPoint(0,0);
    obj_corners[1] = cvPoint( char1.cols, 0 );
    obj_corners[2] = cvPoint( char1.cols, char1.rows );
    obj_corners[3] = cvPoint( 0, char1.rows );



    Mat frame;




    Mat des_image, img_matches;
    std::vector<KeyPoint> kp_image;
    std::vector<vector<DMatch > > matches;
    std::vector<DMatch > good_matches;
    std::vector<Point2f> obj;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene;
    std::vector<Point2f> scene_corners(4);
    Mat H;


    detector.detect( image, kp_image );
    extractor.compute( image, kp_image, des_image );

    matcher.knnMatch(des_object, des_image, matches, 2);

    for(int i = 0; i < min(des_image.rows-1,(int) matches.size()); i++) //THIS LOOP IS SENSITIVE TO SEGFAULTS
    {
        if((matches[i][0].distance < 0.6*(matches[i][1].distance)) && ((int) matches[i].size()<=2 && (int) matches[i].size()>0))
        {
            good_matches.push_back(matches[i][0]);
        }
    }



    //Draw only "good" matches


    drawMatches( char1, kp_object, image, kp_image, good_matches, img_matches, Scalar::all(-1), Scalar::all(-1), vector<char>(), DrawMatchesFlags::NOT_DRAW_SINGLE_POINTS );

    if (good_matches.size() >= 4)
    {
        for( int i = 0; i < good_matches.size(); i++ )
        {
            //Get the keypoints from the good matches
            obj.push_back( kp_object[ good_matches[i].queryIdx ].pt );
            scene.push_back( kp_image[ good_matches[i].trainIdx ].pt );
            cout<<angleBetween(obj[i],scene[i])<<endl; //angles between images

        }

        H = findHomography( obj, scene, CV_RANSAC );


        perspectiveTransform( obj_corners, scene_corners, H);

       // cout<<angleBetween(obj[0], scene[0])<<endl;


        //Draw lines between the corners (the mapped object in the scene image )

    }

    //Show detected matches
    // resize(img_matches, img_matches, Size(img_matches.cols/2, img_matches.rows/2));

    imshow( "Good Matches", img_matches );
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

How to rotate the Incoming Image automatically so that it will align perfectly with the Template Image. i have the following code which rotate the Incoming Image manually 90 degree anticlockwise

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

img = cv2.imread('letter defect f90.png',0)
rows,cols = img.shape

M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D((cols/2,rows/2),90,1)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))

img2 = cv2.imwrite('result_rotate.png',dst)

img3 = cv2.imread('letter f.png')
img4 = cv2.imread('result_rotate.png')

difference = cv2.subtract(img3, img4)

result = np.any(difference) 

if result is True:
    print ("The images are the same")
else:
    cv2.imshow("result.jpg", difference)
    print ("the images are different")
```

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking of coming up with a solution after I got your comment. My answer may not be perfect but hope it gives some idea to a better solution.

Perform a contour operation of the image you intend to find rotation for.
Fit an ellipse around the contour you have obtained.
Now based on the obtained ellipse you can come to a conclusion whether the image is vertical, horizontal or inclined in any other direction.

-If your contour object is broad, the major axis of the ellipse fit will be horizontal.

-If your contour object is thin and tall, the major axis of the ellipse fit will be vertical.

Now if the obtained ellipse fit is neither vertical nor horizontal, you will need to perform an orientation alignment.

Hope it helps!!!!

**EDIT**

I guess you want to rotate your image. You can use the getRotationMatrix2D() function available in the OpenCV library (snippet from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/20/basic-image-manipulations-in-python-and-opencv-resizing-scaling-rotating-and-cropping/)):

```
(x, y) = img.shape[:2]
center = (y / 2, x / 2)

Mat = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, 90, 1.0)
rotate = cv2.warpAffine(img, Mat, (y, x))
cv2.imwrite("rotated.jpg", rotate)
```

- 1st parameter : Initially you obtain the **center** of the image.
- 2nd parameter : Rotate the image around this center with an **angle**
  of your choice.
- 3rd parameter : This is the **scale**. It decides how big or small
  you want your image to be.

Here is your original image:

[image]

This is the rotated image obtained:

[image]

Comment: I used this code snippet from [here](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/01/20/basic-image-manipulations-in-python-and-opencv-resizing-scaling-rotating-and-cropping/). I also has other basic image manipulation techniques.

Comment: It's better to provide proper citation _in the answer_. You can [edit] the answer if you want to provide more details

Comment: miki, how to rotate the image automatically?

Comment: @Shahir what do you mean by automatic? My point is that, you can set a series of conditions then perform rotations based on those conditions.

Comment: @Jeru by automatic i mean the code can detect automatically that the Original Image above is off by 90 degree clockwise [the Image is supposed to be straight and shows 'f'] & automatically rotate it 90 degree anti-clockwise. 

if i have two more misoriented Images e.g. 7 degree anti-clockwise and 51 degree clockwise, i want the code to automatically calculate the 7 degree and 51 degree & rotate automatically clockwise 7 degree and 51 degree anti-clockwise respectively. 

the code is for Vision System. no input by human e.g. enter 7 or 51 or 90 degree, is expected

Comment: I have been thinking about this problem all day. Check out the answer section.